# receive money without other having to set up account

Tags: money-transfer

I'm part of an organisation in Switzerland and we organise events for students. They're from all over the world.

Now we would like for them to be able to pay money online but without them having to set up an account.
I know there are options like paypal, revolut but then we'd have to have a business account which will cost a percentage of the fee which is not really an option.

Question:
Is there a free option to request money from people without them having to set up an account?

Comment: Handing someone cash in person is pretty much the only way to send money that doesn't involve either (or both) parties having an account of some kind and/or some 3rd party keeping a portion of the money as a fee for handling the transaction. I'm not sure the thing you're looking for exists. Since you mention being part of an organization, can we assume that your org already has it's own banking accounts? Or are you starting totally from scratch?

Comment: yeah we do have a bank account, but for the international students that would mean fees as well.
There was a free option from PayPal, but it's no longer available for regular users.

Comment: Even if you use bitcoin, but there will be conversion and transaction fees ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very unlikely that you'll find an a free ongoing service for this.

Anyone who transfers money faces risks from fraud: bad checks, forged money orders, stolen credit cards, hacked bank accounts. No-one could afford to offer this service for free for very long, (particularly internationaly) as they'd go broke from the fraudulent transactions.

Furthermore, companies that do regular international money transfers have to abide by anti-money laundering regulations, once of which is to "know your customer", meaning both of the parties in the transfer have to identify themselves to the transfer agent, which typically means creating an account any paying fees.

If you qualify as a charitable organization, talk to your bank. They may be willing to assist you and your students as a charitable donation.

Comment: alright thanks. With this explanation it makes sense, why there are no more free services like that. I didn't think that far.